# Using jProfiler to generate call graph

Tags: java, profiling, jprofiler, call-graph

I want to use jProfiler to generate a call graph. I have received a licensed key for evaluation version. I want to use jprofiler to profile a simple webserver(jibble miniwebserver). I am using linux. I downloaded the jprofiler_linux_7_1_2.sh file from "http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files.html" and I installed jprofiler by running the downloaded .sh file. Now can anybody **please tell me what should I do to run application server with jprofiler ?** I can run application server without profiling by this command (java -jar Simplewebserver.jar) and also **How do I run my simple java program (having 5 method calls) with jProfiler ?**

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation should be clear on how it works: [jprofiler documentation](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/offline/offline.html).

Answer (score 0):

If You have a GUI on the Linux machine, create a new session in the start center, set the session type to "Application" and choose the JAR file in the "main class or executable jar file" text field. Then you can simply start the session to profile your application.